# Theos for ARM64 doesn't work properly (Clang throws error)

Tags: ios, syntax-error, clang, theos, arm64

i'm having big problems with theos on arm64.
first some information before.

Device: **iPad Air 2 ARM64**

iOS: **8.1.2 jailbroken**

Installed: **Theos, iPhoneOS8.1 SDK, BigBoss Recommended Tools, newest headers from rpetrich.**

## Tweak.xm

```
%hook SBApplicationIcon

-(void)launch{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST"
message:@"message...." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    %orig;
}


%end
```

---

### Makefile

```
export ARCHS = armv7 armv7s arm64
export TARGET = iphone:clang:8.1:8.1
export SDKVERSION=8.1
include $(THEOS)/makefiles/common.mk

TWEAK_NAME = test
test_FILES = Tweak.xm
test_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit
include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk
```

I typed "make" to make a .dylib.

```
Making all for tweak test...
 Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
 Compiling Tweak.xm...
*/bin/sh: **clang++: command not found**
make[2]: *** [obj/Tweak.xm.360b8e67.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [test.all.tweak.variables] Error 2*
```

I'm spending the whole day for this annoying error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have DHowett's version of Theos, it will not work with arm64. As far as I know CoolStar has the best [Theos fork](http://github.com/coolstar/theos/) that supports arm64.

If you follow [these steps](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Setup#On_iOS/) you should have all of the rest of the dependencies, - clang, Darwin-CC tools, etc. - and then you can remove the Theos package and place CoolStar's fork (above) into '/var/theos/'.

For further help you can ask on the #Theos channel of Saurik's IRC server irc.saurik.com for help.

Answer (score 1):

Install LLVM + Clang from Cydia from coolstar repo